# CRM2011: Is it possible to set subgrid value via javascript?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a subgrid on a form, I want to show different value which is calculated base on another field on the form.

I don't want to save to database, just for display purpose, is it possible to set the value use javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer to this is no.

There's no concept of 'calculated fields' in MSCRM, I found this a disappointment when I switched to MSCRM from SalesLogix which does support display-only calculated fields.

The only way you could possibly do this without data changes would be hacking the DOM of the grid control, but this is very much unsupported and could get really, really complicated.

If you're willing to concede to make schematic changes, you could add a new field to the entity, and use a workflow process to update the field on save of the entity.  Then just add this field to your grid.

Comment: I can't add a new field, because this record will also link to other record, which means the "calculated field" will be re-calculated. I can use Silverlight to do it, I just don't want to use a complicated way to complete a simple request but now seems I have to use the complicated way.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a chart with custom calculation on it.

If interested, ask me to know what I mean.